# Is this cracking normal when replastering over a brick wall?

Tags: repair, brick, plaster

My apartment was built in 1910 and has plaster walls throughout. The wall that separates my unit with that of the neighbor has plaster over brick.

After 100 years the plaster started separating from the brick wall and came loose. I decided to remove the loose plaster and re-plaster the wall using a structo-lite base coat. I applied plaster weld bonding agent than a base coat layer / scratch coat.

I woke up this morning and I realized the base coat has cracks all over it! See photos below.

[image: wall after removing loose plaster]

[image]

[image: test]

I guess at this point I was planning to apply a brown second coat but with all the cracks on the base coat, I'm not really sure what to do here.

Any tips recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After a 100 years plaster becoming unstuck might have other problems, especially inside. Might need to find those problems before plastering again.

Comment: Have you noticed any humidity problems

Comment: The original mortar was a wrong mixture and dried to fast, creating cracks leading to failure

Comment: Here, we have many houses that were built back in the days of case-hardened bricks and lime mortar, and I've been told that it's important that the mortar be able to transpire so sealing it with anything less porous than plaster would be questionable. (My house dates back at least to the 1890's, and I have horsehair plaster surviving over some but not all of the brick-over-fieldstone foundation.)

Comment: Perhaps your scratch coat was too wet, causing shrinkage and cracking?

Comment: @huesmann I think that's what happened. The scratch coat was way too wet. I guess the question is how can i move forward? Can i just apply the brown coat on top or fix the cracks first? but how can i fix them?

Comment: @AntoineA.Jaoude not sure what you mean by "brown coat" but you'll want a smooth surface coat to paint.  What were you planning to use sub-paint?

Comment: @Huesmann Brown coat is the term for the coat between the scratch coat and the finish.  It's purpose is to define the flatness of the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: YES
Let the base you put up dry for several days. Then finish the wall. Just be sure to actually mix the correct amounts or you'll have the same issue again.